# How to get sum of columns on per page using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a report using php and mysql. My problem is that i want to display a sum of columns data on per page like the following format.

```
Page 1 of 3
-------------------
col1 | col2 | col3|
-------------------
abc   100.01|15.20|
abc   200.05|20.20|
-------------------
sum  |300.06|35.40|

page 2 of 3

-------------------
col1 | col2 | col3|
-------------------
abc   100.01|15.20|
-------------------
sum  |100.01|15.20|
```

and so on.....

Comment: What defines a page in your database? i.e how could it be used in a query?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `LIMIT` that includes with `offset` of the current page like

```
SELECT SUM(col2),SUM(col3)
FROM myTable
LIMIT offset,limit
```

And foreach page **offset** will be changed.

Comment: Any example using php??

Answer (score 0):

You can set a parameter for calculate the sum in the loop.
After ending the loop, you can echo it.

```
$total = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
   //$val is an array, in which result is stored
   $total = $total + $val[$i];
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this totally from mysql, using the following trick:

```
SELECT t.ID, SUM(t.col1), SUM(t.col2), SUM(t.col3)

FROM 

    (SELECT ID, col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable LIMIT 0,3) as t

GROUP BY t.ID WITH ROLLUP
```

Where `LIMIT 0,3` is the `LIMIT offset,limit` of your pagination.

Comment: How to get page offset?

Comment: offset is a multiple of limit, so if each page has 10 lines then for page 1 offset = limit * 1, for page 2 offset = limit * 2, and so on...

Comment: sorry, the right sintax of LIMIT is `LIMIT offset, limit`.

Comment: actully the formula for offset is `offset = limit * (page - 1)`. The `- 1` is needed because you'll want to return lines starting from line zero.